# Select distinct lines by a field

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am making a select that returns me a table likes this

```
Name      surname
Jhon          a
Jhon          b
Jhon          c
Joe           a
Joe           b
Joe           c
```

But what I need to get is just one occurrence of `Jhon` and one of `Joe` with one of the surnames.

I can only have one `Jhon` with one surname and one `Joe` with a surname..

I cannot make an `order by` because I need to select Name and surname..  Also if I use distinct I will have all Jhons and Joes..

Can you help me?

Comment: Which of the surnames do you want? Does it matter? You could use an aggregate function like this: `select name, max(surname) as surname from table group by name` if you want the last surname (`c`) for example.

Comment: doesn't matter what is the surname... i just want a jhon with an username and a Joe with an username... can you help me?

Comment: I believe I already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use aggregation:

```
select name, max(surname) as surname
from table t
group by name;
```

You can also do something similar with analytic functions:

```
select t.name, t.surname
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by name) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This is particularly useful if you want to get more than one column from the same row.